# Visual Studio Licence for a Medium Orginization

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am working as a developer for a mid-sized (100 employees) company who is mainly into accounts. I am a member of a small IT team of 8 people, that manages the activities and build custom software for the client. We are working with Visual Studio Express 2013.

Also, We have 5 cal licence for SQL Server 2014. Only 4 people are developing on it and rest 4 (Server side and front end developers) are connecting it using the VS application.No other user uses the SQL Server or even know if it exists.However, everyone is on the same LAN and we don't have servers set up.

All was going well but we got a call from one of the Microsoft compliance vendor that we are using VS and we are under licenced.

My organization has put me up to answer the questions and I being a developer have no clue what is happening.

So,

1. Do I really need to buy VS professional 2013 instead of Express edition even when the number of users for vs is only 6 out of 100?
2. For SQL Server do I need to buy 95 more cals for users that don't even use SQL Server?

Comment: Why not ask the same question from the vendor? They are the best to answer.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Thanks for the response.
 I don't have the contact with the vendors directly. I can ask the management to do it but first I needed to be sure what I will be talking about.

Comment: You can pay for what you are using.

Comment: First take a list on what are the Microsoft products you using, and make a note on free editions and licensed versions. Then schedule a call with them. Ask what are the details they want from you, and you can answer them after discussing with your management. its not compulsory to answer in the call itself.

Comment: Revert if you need more help on this.

Comment: "Do I really need to buy VS professional 2013 instead of Express edition" - Read the license for the Express version to determine the answer to that question.

Comment: @Ramhound I did and it doesn't clearly state my concerns

Comment: @ankitsuhail - It actually does.  Locate the section that talks about commericial use, if its allowed, then you can continue to use it.  The SQL Server question can also be answered, but I would talk to somebody who can explain the reason you need more licenses, you shouldn't take license advice from random people.

Comment: @vembutech Thanks for the revert. I think this is a logical way to approch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx

Commercial use of Express products

Visual Studio Express products are available at no charge and may be used for commercial, production usage subject to the license terms provided with each product. For example, you can use Express for Windows to create apps that you can then submit for sale in the Windows Store.

So from that it says that the visual studio express it free for commercial if you don't break the license.

Don't know about the SQL but I'm sure you don't have to buy the 95 license who are not using it.